# Is it possible to partially transition to Android Nav Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to refactor an app, activity by activity to use the new nav component. I can see that it does support multiple activity design but only by creating a nav component for each one. That would mean the effort would need to be across the whole app in one sweep, which is not feasible. 
Is there any other way?

I've encountered several problems navigating between activities that do not use the nav component and activities that do, such as how to pop back to a previous non nav activity from a nav activity using an up arrow or even displaying the up arrow in the home fragment of the second activity.

I tried to manually setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) and declare the parent activity in the Manifest but not only does that solution seem incredibly inaccurate (what if 2 different activities could potentially be parents?) but also forced me to add SINGLE_TOP attribute in order to return to previous state, in total seems like too many bandaids that will surely hit more blocks very soon...

Any suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So after about 2 days of searching and trying things I've found that the best option is to setup the toolbar with the nav component but also replacing the appbar config that uses the nav graph with a default builder - one which has an empty top level fragment list. This change essentially tells the nav component there is no top level fragment so always display the up arrow (at least thats my understanding). Also need to add an up arrow listener to pop the back stack to the previous activity if we detect an event at the start destination (entry fragment)

- There is no need to make any manifest changes or set the appbarhome attributes which I found conflict with the Nav component behaviour..

> Blockquote

```
private fun setToolbar() {
    navController = findNavController(R.id.navigation_host_fragment)
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(
            navController,
            AppBarConfiguration.Builder().build() // Use Builder for empty top level list, up arrow display for home fragment.
    )

    binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        if (navController.currentDestination?.id == navController.graph.startDestination) {
            onBackPressed()
        } else {
            navController.navigateUp()
        }
    }
}
```

> Blockquote

Hope this helps others that ran into the same difficulties transitioning to using the new'ish Nav component!!!